# Equal "YES/NO" Type fields in MS Access query give different results

Tags: database, ms-access

Cheers,

I have a question regarding a query in MS Access (2000, but I don't think the version matters).
Well I have various fields that I query from different tables. 2 "YES/NO"-Data Type fields behave differently in the query. The first, "Inactive" has already existed in the database when I started working with it, the other, "Discarded" I added recently. I compared the fields in the original table (they are from the same table), and to me they are exactly the same:

```
Format:        True/False
Default Value: 0  
Indexed:       No
Text Align:    General
```

*(also, I experimented with different values but no success)*

The problem: Both fields are supposed to show up with either result (the checked checkboxes and the unchecked), but only one does. The other ("Inactive") refuses to show me the checked results, although they are configured equally -

```
Total: Group By
Show: (checked)
```

the other fields are left blank.

edit: the SQL code of the query (*I hope this is not too messy*):

```
SELECT Pc.Name, Ram.Size, Pc.RamSlots, RamType.Name, Room.Name, User.Username,   
Pc.InventoryNumber, Pc.IsInactive, Pc.Discarded, Pc.DateDiscarded
FROM (PC_has_HD INNER JOIN HardDisk ON PC_has_HD.HD = HardDisk.HD_ID) INNER JOIN ([User] INNER  
JOIN (Room INNER JOIN (RamType INNER JOIN (Ram INNER JOIN ((Cpu INNER JOIN Pc ON Cpu.CPU_ID = 
Pc.CPU) INNER JOIN PC_has_RAM ON Pc.PC_ID = PC_has_RAM.PC) ON Ram.RAM_ID = PC_has_RAM.RAM) ON   
RamType.RT_ID = Ram.Type) ON Room.ROOM_ID = Pc.Room) ON User.US_ID = Pc.User) ON PC_has_HD.PC =  
Pc.PC_ID
GROUP BY Pc.Name, Ram.Size, Pc.RamSlots, RamType.Name, Room.Name, User.Username,     
Pc.InventoryNumber, Pc.IsInactive, Pc.Discarded, Pc.DateDiscarded;
```

So, anyone an idea where to look? What to consider? Or do you need more details?
Thanks, Station

Comment: Could you edit your post to show the query you are using please?

Comment: If you add a new field to a table, unless you set the values they default to Null. If you try to filter on the new field you will not get records if the value is still Null. BTW, where in your query is where...

Comment: I tried changing the values of the checkboxes... unfortunately it makes no difference :-( I think my query doesn't need "where", as it is supposed to show all of the selected datasets (need it to create a report)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so a colleague helped me, and the problem was a join with a field where not every dataset has a value. Because it was an inner join these datasets where then missing in the query. We rebuilt the query and now it's working.